# Can't install packages after trying to install .deb file

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, python

I run Ubuntu Unity 22.04, and I've tried to install Crossover from a .deb file. It didn't work, but now whenever I try to install something from the terminal, it defaults to trying to install Crossover.

Here's the screenshot of what happens:
[image: Here's the screenshot of what happens.]

And a transcript:

```
Setting up crossover:i386 (19.0.0-1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/cxoffice/lib/python/cxconfig.py", line 12, in <module>
    from collections import MutableMapping
ImportError: cannot import name 'MutableMapping' from 'collections' (/usr/lib/python3.10/collections/__init__.py)
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/cxoffice/bin/cxtie", line 135, in <module>
    import cxtiemain
  File "/opt/cxoffice/lib/python/cxtiemain.py", line 6, in <module>
    import c4parser
  File "/opt/cxoffice/lib/python/c4parser.py", line 10, in <module>
    import cxproduct
  File "/opt/cxoffice/lib/python/cxproduct.py", line 7, in <module>
    import cxconfig
  File "/opt/cxoffice/lib/python/cxconfig.py", line 15, in <module>
    from UserDict import DictMixin as MutableMapping
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'UserDict'
dpkg: error processing package crossover:i386 (--configure):
 installed crossover:i386 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 crossover:i386
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How do I fix it?

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and official *flavors* of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.   *Ubuntu Unity releases before 22.10 are not official being unofficial respins*

Comment: Apt literally doesn't know the meaning of "failure": Once you tell apt to install something, it will keep trying to install that package. Try `sudo apt-mark remove playonlinux crossover:i386` to tell apt that those packages should be removed instead of installed. Let us know if it works, since there are several possible follow-up errors that you might encounter.

Comment: @user535733 I tried that, and it said that they're marked for removal. But when I try to run apt upgrade, it goes back to trying to install crossover:i386

Comment: I added an answer to your question, but as your q is specifically more of an ubuntu installation hook/package manager issue, I didn't want to distract from the topic. I added a question and answer here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/769613/84665 if you want to be able to install your version of crossover, bypassing that ``ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'UserDict'`` error. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

this is because the CrossOver package tries to execute some Python code functions which were deprecated in Python 3.3 and hence removed in 3.10 which is installed on your system (`/usr/lib/python3.10/...`).

Sure, you definitely need to contact CodeWeavers for an updated version of the package. Downgrading Python to 3.9 might still be another option. but beware of possible dependency issues happening in the future.

Source:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70013988/importerror-cannot-import-name-mutablemapping-from-collections-usr-local

Answer (score 0):

`rm -rd -f /opt/cxoffice`

`rm -f /var/lib/dpkg/info/crossover.postinst`

`apt update`

Then remove the binaries.